# Import and parse spreadsheet (Excel) files in Ruby

Tags: ruby, excel, import, spreadsheet

My model is as follows:

```
class Horse < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.import(file)
    allowed_attributes = ["name","place"]
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      horse = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
      horse.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*Horse.attribute_names())
      horse.save!
    end
  end

 def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    when ".csv" then Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    when ".xls" then Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
  end
 end
```

When I upload an Excel file to my app it is parsed and displayed in a table. The problem I have is that each time I upload an Excel file it creates a new table and pastes it below the previous one.

I want to be able to upload an Excel form with updated numbers that will add to the numbers in the current table.

For example if I have an Excel file that has:

`Kane 1`

then I upload one that has:

`Kane 10`

Then I want the table to show:

`Kane 11` in the row.

Thanks any help appreciated.

Comment: How does your spreadsheet look like and what is `row["id"]`?

Comment: My spreadsheet has 2 columns. One is called `name` and the other is called `place`. I copied `row["id"]` from a tutorial. I believe it is supposed to look to see if a row with a certain "id" already exists, no?

Comment: I was following from Railscast #396

Comment: `find_by_id(row["id"]) || new` tries to find a `Horse` instance with an `id` equal to `row["id"]` or - if no such record exists - creates a new one. Since you don't have an `id` column in your spreadsheet, a new "table" is created every time.

Comment: Oh ok, it's just strange that in the tutorial an `id` column is not created however it still works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've added an answer with the corresponding part from the ASCIIcast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that your spreadsheet data doesn't contain a `id` column. In [RailsCast #369](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel) this column is added to modify existing records. From the corresponding [ASCIIcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast):

> #### Modifying Existing Records
>
> It would be useful if we had an `id` column in our data that could be
>   used to update an existing record instead of adding a new one. This
>   way we could download an CSV file, modify the products in it then
>   upload it to change multiple products at once. If we download our
>   existing products we’ll end up with this CSV data.
>
> **`product.csv`**
>
> ```
> id,name,released_on,price,created_at,updated_at
> 4,Acoustic Guitar,2012-12-26,1025.0,2012-12-29 18:23:40 UTC,2012-12-29 18:23:40 UTC
> 5,Agricola,2012-10-31,45.99,2012-12-29 18:23:40 UTC,2012-12-29 18:23:40 UTC
> 6,Christmas Music Album,2012-12-06,12.99,2012-12-29 20:55:29 UTC,2012-12-29 20:55:29 UTC
> 2,Red Shirt,2012-10-04,12.49,2012-12-29 18:23:40 UTC,2012-12-29 18:23:40 UTC
> 1,Settlers of Catan,2012-10-01,34.95,2012-12-29 18:23:40 UTC,2012-12-29 18:23:40 UTC
> 3,Technodrome,2012-12-22,27.99,2012-12-29 18:23:40 UTC,2012-12-29 18:23:40 UTC
> 7,Unicorn Action Figure,2012-12-06,5.85,2012-12-29 20:55:29 UTC,2012-12-29 20:55:29 UTC
> ```
>
> To get this to work we’ll need to change the way that the products are
>   imported. Instead of creating a product for each row of data we’ll try
>   to find one based on the value in the `id` column. We’ll use `find_by_id`
>   so that nil is returned if a matching record isn’t found and in this
>   case we’ll create a new record. Next we’ll set the product’s
>   attributes based on the data in the row and as this might include
>   attributes we don’t want to set attributes for such as the `id` we’ll
>   update off the only the attributes that are listed in the model’s
>   `attr_accessible` list.